# Changelog file: YAML vs JSON vs CSV

Tags: php, json, logging, csv, yaml

I am creating a simple Changelog lib in CodeIgniter that will basically log a message everytime someone adds, deletes, changes or publish a blog post. I will log messages in files by batches of 300. So every 301st message will go in a new file. At first I wanted to write the logs to simple .log files but then I got the idea to actually style the thing and I had to seperate each "attribute" of each message (ie: the user, the message, the type of the log, etc.). So .log files are out of the question since extracting the info would be a pain.

What is the most appropriate format for such a task? I already ruled out MySQL and XML because they are too heavy (especially considering that the log files won't exceed (about) 300 lines). I suggested YAML vs JSON vs CSV in the title, but is there yet a better alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say it all depends on what you need/want to do with those files :

- CSV has one advantage : it can be imported to Excel and such applications -- which might be usefull in some situations, to do reporting to a superior, for instance
- JSON is readable in many languages, including Javascript ; but not easy to read by a human being ; and harder to modify "by hand"
- And YAML is quite easy to read ; not hard to modify by hand ; but not sure about the availability of libraries to read it in several languages.

If you are in none of these situations :

- must be readable

  - by a human being
  - in several programming languages
- easy to modify

  - same notes

Then I guess all three formats will be OK ^^

Without knowing more, I would go with either CSV *(for the import to Excel stuff)*, or JSON *(for the portability reason)*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your reflections were very interesting. According to the context, I think JSON is the format I will choose.

Answer (score 2):

I guess CSV would be easier because of a couple of reasons:

- count how many logs are already in the list (just count number of lines)
- adding stuff to a JSON object can't be done by just appending data

Of course, I you choose to create a separate JSON object for each log item and put each on a separate line, this isn't an issue.

Comment: You're not going to be reading/writing JSON (or YAML) manually though - you're going to be using a library. And then it's just a matter of `data <- read_json(json); length(data); data += more_data ; json_write(data)`...